# AudioKit AKMicrophone not outputting any data

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, audiokit

I am trying to capture FFT data from a microphone. I've managed to get it to work before with a similar codebase but since macOS Mojave it's broken - the fft data constantly stays 0.

Relevant Code:

```
var fft: AKFFTTap?
var inputDevice: AKDevice? {
    didSet {
        inputNode = nil
        updateAudioNode()
    }
}
var inputNode: AKNode? {
    didSet {
        if fft != nil {
            // According to AKFFTTap class reference, it will always be on tap 0
            oldValue?.avAudioNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
        }

        fft = inputNode.map { AKFFTTap($0) }
    }
}
```

[...]

```
guard let device = inputDevice else {
    inputNode = ViewController.shared.player.mixer
    return
}

do {
    try AudioKit.setInputDevice(device)
}
catch {
    print("Error setting input device: \(error)")
    return
}

let microphoneNode = AKMicrophone()

do {
    try microphoneNode.setDevice(device)
}
catch {
    print("Failed setting node input device: \(error)")
    return
}

microphoneNode.start()
microphoneNode.volume = 3
print("Switched Node: \(microphoneNode), started: \(microphoneNode.isStarted)")

inputNode = microphoneNode
try! AudioKit.start()
```

All the code is called, no errors are output, but the fft simply stays blank. With some code reordering I get varying errors.
A full version of the class, for completeness, is [here](https://gist.github.com/Ivorforce/1ff52d4c9e878e6f6193dcf8a09464ca).

Finally, I also tried implementing one to one the examples from the [playground](https://audiokit.io/playgrounds/Analysis/Tracking%20Microphone%20Input/). Since XCode playgrounds seem to crash with AudioKit, I tried it in my own codebase, but there's no difference there either. AKFrequencyTracker, for example, gets 0s for both amplitude and frequency.

Comment: Playgrounds crash with anything, not just AudioKit, and for for someone like me, who has created hundreds of playgrounds, its a real downer.  That being said, the AKFrequencyTracker playground that tracks the oscillator's frequency, does quite well.  But, microphone-based stuff is a bit suspect right now.  People are looking into it.  I believe it has to do with default microphone choice, but I am not sure.

Comment: In my scenario, you can choose the input device (and the selection itself does work, which I know since invalid audio devices spout lots of errors, lol). But thank you for the heads up, I'll be keeping a look out for changes!

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% positive of this, but I'd like you to try AudioKit v4.5.1 out.  We definitely fixed a bug in AKMicrophone, and that could have downstream consequences.  I'll withdraw this answer and keep looking if it is not fixed. Let me know.

Comment: No changes, I think.

Comment: On setups where I don't attach the microphone to the AudioKit output pipeline, I get no values. Otherwise I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in apples.audio.IOThread and a printed "Woops". 
I have created a minimalistic representation of my setup over at http://ivorius.de/AKMicTest.zip. Maybe it's any help in fixing the issue. (Requires a carthage update before it can be run).